# how to solve that one I could not fund any

Tags: python

Write a program to cheer for your favourite team at the sports carnival. Since I don't play any real world sports, my program would work like this:

```
Cheer: gryffindor
Give me a g, g!
Give me a r, r!
Give me a y, y!
Give me a f, f!
Give me a f, f!
Give me a i, i!
Give me a n, n!
Give me a d, d!
Give me a o, o!
Give me a r, r!
What does it spell?
GRYFFINDOR
```

​
Here's another example of how your program should work:

```
Cheer: hello
Give me a h, h!
Give me a e, e!
Give me a l, l!
Give me a l, l!
Give me a o, o!
What does it spell?
HELLO
```

​
**Code:**

```
name = input('cheer: ')
for c in name:
  print(c)
```

Comment: It seems you're on the right track. I would recommend looking into f-strings and the `end` parameter for `print()` (`print(string, end='')` removed the endline of a print statement).

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
name = input('cheer: ')
for c in name:
    print(f'Give me a {c}, {c}!')
print(f'What does it spell? {name.upper()}!')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
name = input('Cheer: ') 
string = 'Cheer: '+ name + ' '
for c in name: 
  string += 'Give me a ' + c + ', ' + c + '! '
string += 'What does it spell? ' + name.upper()
print(string)
```